# Why is the right half of the circuit irrelevant?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

A follow-up this post regarding the following circtuit:

[image]

---

I continue to struggle to understand why the right half of the circuit is irrelevant when computing the voltage between \$A\$ and \$B\$. One answer to the previous post reads

> The \$500Ω\$ resistor is not short-circuited, but there's effectively only one connection from the left half of the circuit to the right, so the current source and the \$28V\$ voltage source can have no effect on the voltage from \$A\$ to \$B\$.

- Aren't there *two* connections from the left half to the right?

[image]

- Even if there is only one connection, why does that imply the sources in the right half of the circuit cannot have an effect on the voltage from \$A\$ to \$B\$?

Another answer reads

> The right half of the circuit only connects to node \$B\$, there is no path for any current from the \$28 V\$ or \$10 mA\$ sources to flow to node \$A\$, so that whole part of the circuit is irrelevant to the voltage from \$A\$ to \$B\$.

- It seems to me the right half connects to \$A\$:

[image]

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9h93.png) should be all you need to see. There's only one wire between the two sections -- ground. That's all.

Comment: There is no ground indicated in any diagram in the OP. @periblepsis

Comment: @RussellH I get to assign ground to ***any*** node I want. And you know it! Don't pretend otherwise. ;)

Comment: Certainly you can and just as certainly I know it! i make no pretence. Still, choice of ground has no relevance to the answer. :)@periblepsis

Comment: @RussellH It indeed does, as it can help one to ***see*** something obvious that seems otherwise obscured. I use the technique all the time. It just works right, sweeping away the detritus (wiring) that often gets in the way of seeing something more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a current to flow you would need two *independant* nodes between the left and right. The right side only connects to the left at node B. They may have drawn it to look like there are two nodes, but the connections from the right are in fact both to node B, so only one node is connected.

Note that I use the word *[node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(circuits))*. In a schematic a node is a part of the circuit where two or more circuit elements connect, and it is assumed that this connection has zero resistance. It is considered to act as a single point even though it is drawn as lines between the components. So node B includes all of the lines connected to where it says B, up to where they attach to a component.

Here I have highlighted node B, all of the red is considered to be at the same voltage potential, and all of the currents entering and leaving it will sum to zero.
[image]

So as you can see, current coming from node B can't flow around to A and through the 500\$\Omega\$ resistor back to B.
For any current to flow, some part of the right side that's not connected to node B would need to connect to some part of the left side other than node B.

That is why I said in the previous question that the right side of the circuit is irrelevant to the voltage from A to B.

Comment: +1, and I mostly understand now. One small thing, how do we know the currents entering and leaving node \$B\$ must add up to zero? Is _that_ the statement of KCL? I've always interpreted the KCL with a different notion of "node".

Comment: @Sam Yes, KCL. Currents entering must equal currents leaving because where else would they go?

Answer (score 9):

If I redrew it like this would that help: -

[image]

> *Even if there is only one connection, why does that imply the sources
> in the right half of the circuit cannot have an effect on the voltage
> from A to B?*

Because there can be no current through that single path.

Comment: Sadly, no. Why can't any current flow through that wire?

Comment: How would the current return to where it started?

Comment: Of course! I understand now why no current flows through that wire. However, in the original circuit where there are two connections between the left and right halves, could the current not flow from left to right through the upper connection and from right to left through the lower connection?

Comment: @Sam of course it will but, it would have no effect on the voltages across nor the currents through any of the components on the left circuit.

Comment: Yes, and it probably does. But as the two connections go to the same point, the amount coming from the right hand side must balance with the amount going back to the right hand side and therefore has no effect on the left hand side.

Comment: @Finbarr - For clarity, who is your comment intended to be addressed to? Please use the [`@username` reply notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) when there is any ambiguity who the intended recipient is. TY